# In Python how can I make this model check against the audio output stream for a PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, audio, audio-streaming

I have been following the tutorial on [Audio Recognition for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition).

I have trained a model, and I want to run that model against a constant stream which is the audio output device on a computer. I.e whatever is coming out of the speakers. The model is super simple, and not complicated testing for a very simple tone, the model is almost certainly overtrained but at this point I am not concerned about this. The output from the training is:

```
I0911 19:29:05.357377 4477539776 fishem.py:268] Step 250: Validation accuracy = 100.0% (N=4)
I0911 19:29:05.357587 4477539776 fishem.py:276] Saving to "logs/commands_train/conv.ckpt-250"
I0911 19:29:05.419842 4477539776 fishem.py:280] set_size=4
W0911 19:29:05.487061 4477539776 fishem.py:299] Confusion Matrix:
 [[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
W0911 19:29:05.487216 4477539776 fishem.py:301] Final test accuracy = 100.0% (N=4)
```

The article doesn't explain how to set a model to check against an audio stream such as this, instead focussing on a [generated stream of audio](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition#streaming_accuracy) and mobile device audio streams.

This is a question both for Python and TensorFlow communities, given a model generated using the initial article, how can I make it test against the audio output on a computer.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is a while loop without any breaking condition. Within this while loop, you'll have to capture the audio stream (with [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) for example) and vectorize it to the same vector input structure of your model. Next, you will have to feed this vector to your model and capture the event that you are interested in.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your response. When you say Vectorize I am not sure what you mean. My model can be tested against a wav file for example?

Comment: Vectorizing is taking the audio data, and turn it into numeric input data for your model.

Comment: Is there an example of doing such an approach. It makes sense, but given my clip is around a second, do I sample every second, or is there a way to constantly compare to the model as quick as possible? An example would be terrific.